# Disable Linux Scheduler to meter power consumption of specific machine code instructions

Tags: linux, kernel, real-time, scheduler

how can i run a programm in linux thats runs about 10000 times a shift instruction without it being interrupted by the scheduler? I want to do so in order to examine power consumption of the native shift instruction.

Answer (score 0):

The scheduler is not going to interrupt your task unless something else needs to run. Hardware interrupts (e.g. timers) will happen though, and they interrupt it for a while, but not very long normally.

However, I'm really not sure how measuring the power of a particular instruction is relevant; modern CPUs don't really work like that - they don't ever run just one instruction at once, and no "real" program uses just a single type of instruction.

I don't think the impact of hardware interrupts is going to be very much, especially if you're running a "tickless" kernel (which is usually enabled by default on newer systems).